# how add image in RecentBlogPost widget, Orchard CMS

Tags: image, orchardcms, blogs

In Blog Post Content Type i have Media Library Picker Field named "BlogPostImage". In placement.info i add:  `<Match ContentType="BlogPost">
       <Match DisplayType="Summary">
          <Place Fields_MediaLibraryPicker="Content:1"/>
       </Match>
     </Match>`

So picture show in summary page, i wanna that the same picture show in Recent Blog Widget. How do that?

Comment: That Widget uses the Summary view of the blog posts so the image should be displayed. https://orchard.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Orchard.Web/Modules/Orchard.Blogs/Drivers/RecentBlogPostsPartDriver.cs

Answer (score 1):

You have to override the shape template.
In views\Parts.Blogs.RecentBlogPosts.cshtml

See example from this theme : https://bitbucket.org/psenechal/pjs.bootstrap
a MediaPickerField called BlogPostImage is used in views\Content-BlogPost.Summary.cshtml